# User Experience Flow on iOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

Under iOS there are several built in hooks for launching service-specific apps based on a passed URL for example handling http:// (to Safari), handling addresses (to google maps) and phone numbers (to the built in phone app). Several apps make it a standard practice of implementing the rarely used ability (for most apps) to register your own service prefix.  Two handy apps that come to mind that implement this are facebook:// and skype:// and it is a handy way to add quasi-integration with their app into yours. Skype even does this on most desktop os's so you can literally run the command line skype://555-1234.  You can also check for these registered service prefixes and expose useful menu choices in your apps but I digress.

As with all of these service handlers built in or not, the problem under iOS is that you lose the user and the flow of their experience ends with the phone app (for example). Yes you can embed web views to handle some cases but things like the phone app still win out.

I propose that it would be great that if iOS apps were handed a trailing URL as part of their arguments (even if they accept and might handle say two args already) that by convention when our app is exited we launch the trailing URL we may have been optionally handed.  If fully supported in some manner this would allow for multi-app integration and an extended user experience flow-wise.  I'm imagining being able for example to launch a phone call and have the user return to my app when it is finished by launching my app again using the URL I passed it such as "myapp://return-context-values". Obviously this could be taken further.

Does such a mechanism already exist in some way? If not I'd like to hear your thoughts on the idea.

Comment: This already works with oauth. If you set the oauth_callback to be your application url in step A, when the user is redirected in step D it will open your application again. http://oauth.net/core/diagram.png

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out **[x-callback-url.com](http://x-callback-url.com/)**, it proposes precisely what you're suggesting.

And yes, I think it would be great. You're much more likely to pass a request to me if you know you'll get the focus back, and vice versa.

Comment: Thanks for the reference Matthew. I had not heard of that proposal and yes they are talking about the same issue.  This would even be a great construct to see implemented on the web in general iOS apps notwithstanding.

Comment: @Ripred, how do you mean in general?  This is an excellent idea for iOS, how do you mean for the web?  Sounds intriguing...

Comment: @Clark: Well even if the callback URL wasn't an iOS specific registered URL scheme (could just be an http return address) the idea that all of our sites observed the symantecs of returning to a passed URL intrigues me too.  Think being logged into your grocery store making a your shopping list and then jumping to your favorite recipe site, select the ingredient list as a return value (and give the recipe site some eyeballs as a perk) and then return that back to your shopping list. That's a contrived example off of the top of my head but could be a more fluid internet experience as a user

Comment: @Amigable In that last context I was referring to how this could be used in browser environments although my original post was indeed only about solving the lost user issue in iOS.